# Is there a way to change an http request, response location?

Tags: javascript, php, api, post, get

I'm making a call to an api, but I need to change the location of the response... Typically, the response will be sent directly back to the client making the call, but I need a way to send that response elsewhere. 
[image]

Is this even possible? Is there a work around to do this?
The server is an api like paypal or facebook, and the client is not the same location.

Thanks!

Comment: I'm not a web developer but I'm quite sure the answer is no. Client open a stream to server and server answer on that stream. In your scenario server should open a new stream to the client and send the answer: that means client become a server :).

Comment: To clarify, "client" is my server, not a browser instance.

Comment: Your *client* make web requests. So it is a client from socket point of view.

Comment: I believe this is exactly the way IP spoofing works. Basicly you're modifying your IP layers forcing the server to send the reply to another client. The downside to this is that the requesting client will never receive a response and therefor has no idea if the request was succesfull or not.

Comment: @icecub IP spoofing does not happen on the _http_ protocol layer.

Comment: @icecub It's okay for me if the first server doesn't get a response, as long as server 2 gets it.

Comment: Well like @collapsar already said: IP spoofing doesn't happen on the http protocol layer. Besides that, I agree with his answer to your question. Maybe you should explain what exactly you're trying to accomplish? I'm pretty sure there are other ways to do it.

Comment: @icecub I have a client with his/her own api key on their local computer. They make requests to a third party server, and I need to get the response data without the possibility of them tampering it. (so I can't have the client send me the data)... I can't use oauth in my scenario.

Comment: @BrianSmith So you effectively have someone request protected information from a third party that will never be delivered but instead be diverted to you ? I am very sorry, but offhand this seems a bit smelly to me - why cannot you request the 3rd party information yourself ? Or check a fingerprint of the information received with the 3rd party to safeguard against tampering ?

Answer (score 1):

It won't work (easily).

The http protocol says that the logical client initiates the exchange of information by submitting a request and (hopefully) receives a response. While it may be technically feasible for a server to feed a reponse to client B ('my server 2') with the data whose acquisition was triggered by a request from client A ('my server 1'), i would consider it a blatant violation of privacy and a gross security hole. Note that it still presumes that both clients involved have submitted requests whose liveness intervals overlap.

This does not rule out the possibility that client B be notified by some other means ( eg. Web Sockets ).

However, you still need the cooperation of logical client B ('my server 2'). So the question is whether you better model your application differently, letting 'server' and 'my server 1' swap their logical roles:

- 'my server 2' requests some information from 'server', which ultimately needs to be provided by 'my server 1'.
- 'server' processes this request by submitting a request to 'my server 1'
- the result of this request will be forwrded to 'myserver 2'.

note that the communication between 'server' and 'my server 1' does not need to employ http.

Comment: Is it still possible even if it's under the same domain, just a different location? I can imagine you could handle dynamic ip under your domain to send it to a different server ip... You could imagine a company having multiple servers serving the same domain. It would, in a sense, take the response url and send it to another server ip.

Comment: @BrianSmith Http communication uses 'http connections' which are initiated by the client. Even if the application scenario would be legitimate from the privacy/security point of view, i still think the flow of information will be very unstable and will engender high latencies.

Comment: From my understanding, on server load balancers you can send a request from one server, you may get a response on another. The load balance is handled somewhere and redirects the response accordingly. So I think it's possible.

Comment: @BrianSmith That load balancer conceptually is a proxy and picks an idle server to handle the http request. Thus load balancing takes place prior to  request processing. The information flow you want is implementable; however, i was under the impression that you asked for a built-in http mechanism and I don't think there is one.